# SSIS Package run from SQL Server Agent Job no longer do Logging

Tags: sql-server-2008, logging, ssis, sql-server-agent

I Have a package stored in SQL Server which works properly with logging when I run it directly by right-clicking it in SQL Server, with logging.

Logging is set to 'SSIS log provider for Text File'.

When I run it from an SQL Server Agent Job, it works fine, without errors but the logging isn't done.

The job runs with the my user, the same one that I use to start the package from SQL Server

Anyone know why and how to make it log

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem, my job is own by my user but each step is executed by `SQL Server Agent Service Account`, which didn't have access to rhe folder containing my logs.

I don't understand why there are no errors raised by this...